# Jquerymobile popup on index page; not centering in window and close button will not show

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

Here is what we have in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TyhnV/17/

This line

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetMobileSecurityText", "Page")'
```

is just going to the controller and returning a JSON with HTML strings.

When you first click on the icon to get the popup, the X for the close button (should have been top right) seems to almost appear and then vanishes.  As well, the popup is not centered in the window.  If you click off the popup and then open it again, the popup will be centered in the window, but the X for the close button will still not be there.

Why is my close button not appearing, and why does the first opening of the popup not center it in the window?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("#securityOverlay").html()`, you replace all elements inside popup div. You should use `.append()` instead.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TyhnV/23/)**

Comment: That appends every time the user clicks on the icon for the pop up, though.

Comment: @cookiekitty you can also create popups on the fly. Or add a div inside the popup to`.html()` what you want without affecting popups's structure by using `.html()` on popup div itself.

Comment: How would I make a dynamic popup with the POST ajax call?

Comment: @cookiekitty please post another question with more details.